# How to use Slick code generator to include database views as well?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-generation, slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to generate the Scala code for the database tables and views in my schema using Slick 3.0.3. Taking [this blog](http://arnaudt.github.io/2015/03/31/slick-codegen.html) as example I have the following file `build.sbt`. However, this will generate code for my database tables and will not include the database views. How can I get the views generated as well?

According to [slick issue 1022](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1022) I see it is possible to do but the API doesn't look alike and `slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator` doesn't have a `getTables` or `defaultTables` to include view names.

```
name := "slickCodeGen"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.0.3",
  "org.postgresql" %  "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
  "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.3.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)

slick <<= slickCodeGenTask

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask

lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
  val outputDir = (dir / "main/slick").getPath
  val username = "postgres"
  val password = "xxx"
  val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/testdb?searchpath=public"
  val jdbcDriver = "com.postgresql.jdbc.Driver"
  val slickDriver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver"
  val pkg = "folder1.folder2"
  toError(r.run("slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, username, password), s.log))
  val fname = outputDir + "/folder1/folder2/" + "Tables.scala"
  Seq(file(fname))
}
```

Comment: Honestly - I haven't had much success with Slick-driven DDL that would include views. I ended up specifying views in raw SQL and just mapping them onto classes. I'm anxious to see if you're going to get any replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error due to the many changes in the Slick generator API the following standalone application `Generator.scala` tested **will generate the code for both tables and views under Slick 3.0.3**:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import slick.driver.PostgresDriver
import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable
import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object Generator extends App {
  val slickDriver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver"
  val jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5555/testdb?searchpath=public"
  val outputDir = "/tmp/"
  val pkg = "folder1.folder2"
  val username = "postgres"
  val password = "xxx"

  val db = Database.forURL(url, user, password)
  val dbio = PostgresDriver.createModel(Some(MTable.getTables(None, None, None, Some(Seq("TABLE", "VIEW")))))
  val model = db.run(dbio)
  val future : Future[SourceCodeGenerator] = model.map(model => new SourceCodeGenerator(model))
  val codegen : SourceCodeGenerator = Await.result(future, Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
  codegen.writeToFile(slickDriver, outputDir, pkg, "Tables", "Tables.scala")
}
```

Integrating this code into a `build.sbt` is not that easy because requires defining an external custom code generator file and then compiling and running it from the `build.sbt` before the actual project is compiled. A very outdated example of this can be found in the github project [slick-codegen-customization-example](https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-customization-example) but note that they don't have a `build.sbt` but a more advanced `Build.scala`

Comment: I had managed to get pretty far on my own, but when I had seen other usages of MTable I was sure that `Seq("TABLE","VIEW")` was just a placeholder for the actual names of tables and views you wanted to include, but no it's meta-data. There's an hour I won't get back.