# What's DBIO and how can I get the underlying object?

Tags: scala, slick

While using Slick 3.0.3 and in the context of trying to solve this question [how-to-use-slick-code-generator-to-include-database-views-as-well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756629/how-to-use-slick-code-generator-to-include-database-views-as-well) I get as far as this:

```
import slick.dbio.DBIO
import slick.model.Model
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver
import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable
import slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator

val model : DBIO[Model] = PostgresDriver.createModel(Some(MTable.getTables(None, None, None, Some(Seq("table1","table2","view1")))))
// SourceCodeGenerator requires a Model and not a DBIO[Model]
val codegen = new SourceCodeGenerator(model)
```

It looks almost there, however `PostgresDriver.createModel` returns a `DBIO[Model]` and not a `Model` and I don't see how to extract the model or for that matter run the generator with such model reference. What's this DBIO anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DBIO` is a type of `DBIOAction`. A `DBIOAction` is an action that can be taken on the database. But it has not been executed on the database yet. You need to create a connection to your database to get a database object, and pass the `DBIO[Model]` object to it, which should return a `Future[Model]`.

EDIT:

For info on creating a database object, see: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.2/gettingstarted.html

You need to have the right config in application.conf. Then, you can use code such as:

```
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    val dbio = PostgresDriver.createModel(Some(MTable.getTables(None, None, None, Some(Seq("table1","table2","view1")))))
    val modelF = db.run(dbio) //Produces Future[Model]
    val genF = modelF.map(model => new SourceCodeGenerator(model)) //Produces Future[SourceCodeGenerator]
```

Comment: Thank you! could you complete the answer by showing a pseudo solution to the OP code?